# CasperJS continuously test if selector exists

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am doing some scraping with casperjs and while running the script, I should also test if there is a technical difficulties page appearing. This page can occur anytime while browsing the site, so I can't just put one test in the beginning, it should test continuously. Is there a way in CasperJS/PhantomJS, like a listener or anything?

Should run this:

```
casper.checkIfThereIsTechError = function() {
    return casper.evaluate(function() {
        return __utils__.exists({
            type: 'xpath',
            path: '//a[@href="......'
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in casper js, everything is represented as a step. Inside each step, call your function first to check for errors

```
  casper.then(
  function(){
   isErrorexists = casper.checkIfThereIsTechError()
   if (!isErrorexists){
    do what you want to do here...
       }
     }
  )
```